# Android emulator "cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory"

Tags: android, android-emulator, qemu

I am attempting to run a headless Android emulator on a Ubuntu server. So I built the emulator image from the official AOSP code and tried to start the emulator. However, the emulator crashes after some seconds with an `file_io_posix.cc` error (see the log below).

Crash Log:

```
emulator -no-window -qemu -nographic -machine virt -no-audio
INFO    | Android emulator version 34.1.1.0 (build_id 10728531) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: , detection is enabled for process: 1169196
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each individual line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
INFO    | Increasing RAM size to 2048MB
WARNING | encryption is off
WARNING | FeatureControl is requesting a non existing feature.
INFO    | No consent for crashreport d1f677d0-ebf2-485e-b9db-ac21cdc4c854, deleting.
INFO    | No consent for crashreport 85bb6dd2-bf94-4de0-88ca-32e7f41ec9da, deleting.
INFO    | No consent for crashreport 446c7595-4055-41d6-8a6e-3b13ffe79ebe, deleting.
INFO    | No consent for crashreport cd8e4ea1-46f1-471a-b1f2-0607d095cc8c, deleting.
INFO    | No consent for crashreport 4a160212-b614-4021-baa8-5acc919274f0, deleting.
INFO    | No consent for crashreport 6001ccf7-c4c9-4dde-8896-fa7085cbaf47, deleting.
INFO    | No consent for crashreport 34b22bac-b834-4135-a7b3-ff313a4e82b6, deleting.
INFO    | No consent for crashreport 220d72dc-df65-4506-87e7-260b6729f581, deleting.
INFO    | No consent for crashreport 8f6abc7f-aaaf-4b63-9ead-8f4370560a6d, deleting.
INFO    | No consent for crashreport ae562736-f075-47e7-8e38-f7e83005f66c, deleting.
INFO    | No consent for crashreport 47bd7364-75bc-4dc0-bae3-e9268fc11359, deleting.
INFO    | No consent for crashreport ea7d40c0-db44-44f2-ab27-89973f2df414, deleting.
WARNING | FeatureControl is requesting a non existing feature.
WARNING | FeatureControl is requesting a non existing feature. (4x)
WARNING | Your GPU drivers may have a bug. Switching to software rendering.
library_mode swangle_indirect gpu mode swangle_indirect
WARNING | FeatureControl is requesting a non existing feature.
WARNING | cannot add library /home/suth/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so: failed
INFO    | added library /home/suth/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so
WARNING | The emulator now requires a signed jwt token for gRPC access! Use the -grpc flag if you really want an open unprotected grpc port
INFO    | Using security allow list from: /home/suth/aosp/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib/emulator_access.json
WARNING | *** Basic token auth should only be used by android-studio ***
INFO    | The active JSON Web Key Sets can be found here: /run/user/1004/avd/running/1169196/jwks/bc8a0ede-1c99-47e1-af51-12a281ad3908/active.jwk
INFO    | Scanning /run/user/1004/avd/running/1169196/jwks/bc8a0ede-1c99-47e1-af51-12a281ad3908 for jwk keys.
INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local, auth: +token
INFO    | Advertising in: /run/user/1004/avd/running/pid_1169196.ini
[1169200:1169200:20231012,133519.376099:ERROR file_io_posix.cc:144] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2)
[1169200:1169200:20231012,133519.376205:ERROR file_io_posix.cc:144] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)
```

System version:

```
Linux fmd-aosp 5.15.0-86-generic #96-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 20 08:23:49 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Emulator version:

```
Android emulator version 34.1.1.0 (build_id 10728531) (CL:N/A)
```

I figured out from the log that for some reason the emulator is searching for files in the `cpufreq' folder and that this folder does not exist on the host machine. So I installed cpufreq via the apt "acpi" package. However, when starting acpi it shows "No support for device type: power_supply". Thus, it seems there is no way for me to install cpufreq.

Is there a way to start the Android emulator without the cpufreq file requirement?

Comment: Hey @Vall0n, I did not find a solution to start the emulator without the cpufreq requirement. As workaround, I set "CPU P-state" to "Cooperative" in the BIOS of the host, which allows the virtual machine to access the CPU frequency. However, it's just a workaround and not a good solution for me.